# Unity How to have only one source audio?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a source audio with this code:

```
public class Sound : MonoBehaviour {

    Static Sound instance;
    

    void Awake() 
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

So when i change scenes the audio starts playing again. How do i limit it to having only 1?

Edit: How do i fix that? i get this error
1 - Unexpected symbol `instance' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 2 -  Unexpected symbol` ;' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: How to i make it only once?

Comment: Use a Singleton pattern. Have a static instance and if already set destroy the new one.. see e.g. [In Unity, how do I correctly implement the singleton pattern?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern)

Comment: [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) ist written with a small `s` ...

Comment: Speedy @derHugo. Got the darn comment out before I could get the Answer posted hahah. Props because you totally got the same answer at the same time as me. I wish there was a way to split the rep with you

Comment: @whathm lol actually the first was an hour earlier :P no worries .. this community isn't about rep but people helping others to learn ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

The Singleton Pattern is likely to be your best choice when it comes to things like this. The intent of the Singleton Pattern is to restrict a class to only one Instance of itself. To read more about the pattern, see the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on it.

It looks like you are already doing this (after your first edit) but the thing you're going to want to change is the capitalization of `Static` in your code. `Static` and `static` are two different things. For your sake, you are looking for `static`. This should fix your problem/error and allow you to use the Singleton Pattern correctly.

**Option 2:**

Also, another option if you want to avoid the typical Singleton Pattern would be to search through all GameObjects for any that have you `Sound` Class/Component on it. Then if there is already on in scene, have the GameObject that is trying to instantiate, destroy itself. You can do this with the following code:

```
public class Sound : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Awake() 
    {
        int numSoundInstances = FindObjectsOfType<Sound>().Length;
        if (numSoundInstances > 1)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this is way less efficient then using the Singleton Pattern. This is because using FindObjectsOfType forces the code to check every GameObject that is currently in the game. Depending on the amount of GameObjects in the game, this can be very taxing on the system.